# Can I use a skill to advantage itself?

Tags: fate, fate-core

This is a quick question for which I don’t think there is a specific rule, but it make sense.

I want to use a skill to create an Advantage, and then use the advantage to improve the same skill.
E.g.:

- Use acrobatic to create “rolling at high speed” and the next round roll at high speed to perform a great jump;
- Use deceive to make sb “believe a dragon is coming”, and the next round make him believe my house is a safe house, he has just t to pay 100 gold;
- Use Physique to create “weak door hinges”, and the next round use the advantage to pull out the door;
- And so on.

On one hand, no rule deny to use an advantage for the same skill of the advantage.
On the other hand, it seems redundant to use a skill to make the action and to support the action (by the advantage).

How do you play? I rather prefer the latter.

Comment: Not at all redundant... it's perfectly reasonable for (e.g.) a swordsman to use his sword skills to set up opportunities, or for a con-artist to set up a foundation of lies on which to build their bigger lies.

Answer (score 6):

FATE Core page 110 has a precedent for using Fight to Create an Advantage that can later be exploited, implicitly with Fight:

> Create an Advantage: You’ll probably use Fight for most of the
> advantages you create in a physical conflict. Any number of special
> moves can be covered with advantages: a targeted strike to stun,
> a “dirty move,” disarming, and so on. You could even use Fight
> to assess another fighter’s style, spotting weaknesses in his or her
> form that you can exploit.

Similarly, Shoot (on page 125) has a Stunt that from context clearly refers to CaAs made with Shoot:

> Uncanny Accuracy. Once per conflict, stack an additional free invoke
> on an advantage you’ve created to represent the time you take to aim
> or line up a shot (like In My Sights).

So precedents exist for a Skill to enhance itself with CaA.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, but this depends on the fiction rather than the rules.

You've outlined a few situations where a skill might be used to Create Advantage in order to set up for some other type of action — probably an Overcome, but that depends on the situation which explains why the PCs are doing these actions in the first place.

In the case of your Deceive example, I'm wondering why it wouldn't just be a single action to tell an NPC "A dragon is coming! Luckily for you, I can lead you to a safe house for 100 gold; your life is worth more than that, right?" But that's because I don't know the broader context of what's happening in the story you have in mind. Maybe you're making a crowd of people panic with rumors of a dragon (setting up an advantage), in order to more easily single out an important nobleman to fleece them for cash (the main goal). And I think that's fine, because even if the GM declares these are both Deceive actions, circumstances might mean that different PCs have to participate in each step, and they might have individual Aspects or Stunts that make inciting panic in a group vs. fast-talking a solo mark more effective.

Finally, although you're asking about Create Advantage specifically, for the sake of completeness I'll mention one case that restricts characters from using the same skill back-to-back: during a [Challenge](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/challenges), each step is designed to roll Overcome with a different skill. The *Fate Core* book has example Stunts that modify this rule, enabling a PC to substitute one skill for another and specifying that this allows using a particular skill twice in the same Challenge.